# I cannot instantiate my bean using @Inject and Vaadin CDI

Tags: jakarta-ee, vaadin, cdi, vaadin7

I am trying to inject my components and beans using Vaadin-cdi. Note the code below is simplified a bit.

```
@Theme("valo")
@CDIUI("")
public class MyUI extends UI {

    @Inject
    private CDIViewProvider provider;

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        Navigator navigator = new Navigator();
        navigator.addProvider(provider);
        navigator.navigateTo("mypanel");  
    }   
}
```

And here goes MyPanel:

```
@CDIView("mypanel")
public class MyPanel extends com.vaadin.ui.Panel implements View {
    @Inject
    private MySubPanel mySubPanel;    

    @Override
    public void enter(ViewChangeListener.ViewChangeEvent event) {
        FormLayout layout = new FormLayout();
        layout.addComponent(mySubPanel);
        this.setContent(layout);
    }
}
```

And here is the MySubPanel class:

```
@UIScoped
public class MySubPanel extends Panel {

    @Inject
    private MyBean myBean;
    public MySubPanel() {
        myBean.createSomething("Something");  // throws NullPointerException
    }
}
```

And finally the MyBean class:

```
@Stateless
@Default
public class MyBean implements Serializable {
    private String something;
    public void createSomething(String something) {
        this.something = something;
    }
}
```

So why does not my bean in `MySubPanel` beeing injected?

I have an empty `beans.xml` and I am using WildFly 8.1.

Comment: Have you tired @EJB instead of @Inject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the constructor class variables are not yet injected. The bean will be injected after initialising, so it is null in the constructor. You have 2 possibilities.

- Inject the bean in the Constructor.
- Use the bean in an init method annotated with @PostConstruct

I'd recommend the second approach. Here you will find more about the different injection methods: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/java-ee-cdi-dependency-injection-inject-tutorial.html